# Algorithm to find high-scoring strings, where score is determined by wildcard-based ruleset

Tags: design-patterns, algorithms, optimization

This is an optimisation problem involving string matching with wildcards. We have a set of wildcard patterns, each tagged with a numerical "score", as below.

```
  Pattern    Score
  *AA*       20
  *ABB*      10
  *BA*       5
  *C*        -5
  *B*A*      -10
  *AAAA*     -100
```

In this example the vocabulary, *V*, is `{A, B, C}`.

A normal string (a string without wildcards) can be assigned a score by taking the sum of scores of the wildcard patterns that match it.

The rule for counting the number of matches of a wildcard pattern within a normal string is that, for each unique match, the leftmost non-wildcard character of the wildcard pattern must match a different character of the normal string. For example, the leftmost non-wildcard character of `*B*A*` is `B`. `*B*A*` thus matches the normal string `BABAAA` two times, not seven.

Example normal-string scores:

```
  String     Score
  ABB        10
  ABBABB     5
  CAAA       35
  CAAAA      -45
  BAACBAC    0
```

The goal is to generate strings over *V* that have the highest possible score (or, failing that, a "reasonably high" score) for a given maximum string length.

Efficiency is important: the maximum string length, the vocabulary size, and the number of wildcard patterns could each be > 100, and so the solution space can be quite large.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi, Doc Brown. So far, I have only achieved a couple of small improvements over a pure brute-force approach, and these are just placeholders. A primitive evolutionary algorithm makes 1-character mutations to the current highest-scoring strings; this works but it is highly inefficient. I have considered simply using a genetic algorithm for the task and optimising its parameters empirically, but I wonder if there isn't a more elegant solution.